# Java HMACSha1 WooCommerce Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.","data":{"status":401}

Tags: java, android, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make GET Request to our Woocommerce store but I'm struggling to get the correct signature for the url.

This is so that I can build an Android and iOS mobile app. I've checked the Woocommerce Java API @ 'https://github.com/icoderman/wc-api-java' and it throws me off a bit.

I have managed to send successful get requests with postman... and gotten the desired results, this is the postman link url:
`https://www.xxx.co.za/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=10&oauth_consumer_key=ck_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1547365367&oauth_nonce=bdMWVEdOwtJ&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=0ztOczZezZhmWEhl0bKS0CP+8TQ&page=2`

I managed to find code that helped me to get started on GitHub @ https://github.com/rameshvoltella/WoocommerceAndroidOAuth1

I've simply rebuilt the project as a java project and not an Android project and I've added the Woocommerce library as packages to combine it into a single application

I made changes to the HMACSHA1SignatureService.java String bytesToBase64Strin() method to:

```
private String bytesToBase64String(byte[] bytes)
{
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}
```

Uses: `import java.util.Base64;`

These are the read only credentials:

`Base Site: www.xxx.co.za`

`Consumer Key: ck_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

`Consumer Secrete Key: cs_1111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

I've also `tried alternating between HTTP and HTTPS`

Comment: Publishing credentials on a platform like Stackoverflow is not a good idea even if they are limed to read-only. Please be aware that this means everybody can access your shopping system now!

Comment: Alright, changed them. Pardon the new url. It was not my intention... Thanks

Comment: Note that the old version of your question is still available. Therefore if the credentials allow access to a real system change/disable the credentials.